# How does one correctly cleanup a asynchronous callback from a forcefully terminate pipe?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-3.5, named-pipes

I'm trying to create a defensive named pipe server which other applications can read a simple state value. I'm interested in only having a single named pipe instance where the client would connect, read the state and disconnects.

The issue I am having is trying to safeguard my pipe from improper usage; specifically preventing a single process from taking control and never letting go of my named pipe. I've attempted to force a disconnect/close of the pipe after a timeout to terminate the connection; the attempt allows my server to proceed, however, the async callback is not called when I end a connection.

A minimized version of my code is as follows (.NET 3.5)...

Server Side]

```
  static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("TestSimplePipe", PipeDirection.Out);

      Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...");
      pipe.WaitForConnection();

      Console.WriteLine("About to BeginWrite...");
      pipe.BeginWrite(new byte[1] { 0x00 }, 0, 1, new AsyncCallback(ProcessWrite), pipe);

      Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
      bool hasSignal = autoEvent.WaitOne(5000);
      if (hasSignal == false)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Client took to long.");
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Closing pipe.");
      pipe.Close();
      Console.ReadLine();
  }

  static void ProcessWrite(IAsyncResult result)
  {
      try
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Ending write...");
          NamedPipeServerStream pipe = result.AsyncState as NamedPipeServerStream;
          pipe.EndWrite(result);

          Console.WriteLine("Wrote successfully!");
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Write not completed.");
      }

      autoEvent.Set();
  }
```

Client Side]

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      using (NamedPipeClientStream npcs = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "TestSimplePipe", PipeDirection.In))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server...");
          npcs.Connect();
          Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

          //Thread.Sleep(15000);

          Console.WriteLine("Reading byte...");
          npcs.ReadByte();
          Console.WriteLine("Byte read!");
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Done!");
      Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

If everything is designed as planned, I get the following outputs:

Server Side]

```
    Waiting for client...
    About to BeginWrite...
    Waiting...
    Ending write...
    Wrote successfully!
    Closing pipe.
```

Client Side]

```
    Connecting to server...
    Connected!
    Reading byte...
    Byte read!
    Done!
```

However, if I enable the sleep in the client side code, the server will not output anything from the callback:

```
    Waiting for client...
    About to BeginWrite...
    Waiting...
    Client took to long.
    Closing pipe.
```

I assumed that on the close, the callback would be called and an 'ObjectDisposedException' would be thrown. Instead, the callback is not called when I close my server pipe.

What also scares me is that if I wait the entire duration of the client's sleep without ending my server pipe application, the callback will be called on the server and I will receive the following output for the server:

```
    Waiting for client...
    About to BeginWrite...
    Waiting...
    Client took to long.
    Closing pipe.
    Ending write...
    Write not completed.
```

I'm not worried about cleaning up the async call, but worried that it somehow stays alive due to a third party application. How can I correctly cleanup the asynchronous callback when I terminate the pipe the callback is attached to?

Comment: Hm is there no way to have multiple connections on one named pipe endpoint?

Comment: There is; it is just not shown in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the same named pipe multiple times. You are supposed to accept multiple clients concurrently. That way no single client can block the endpoint. [This is shown in a native code example on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) You can port that code to .NET. Probably, you should use async IO so that you don't run out of threads with many clients.

On the other hand a malicious client can probably either cause resource exhaustion or starve other clients from ever connecting by spamming the server with connections. I'm not aware of any way to guard against that.

Comment: I agree that supporting concurrent connections will prevent other clients from blocking the named pipe. However, I was trying to understand why a 'malicious' client can someone keep an async callback alive without having the ability to forcefully terminate it (I'm sure there are other ways a client can misuse the pipe, but focusing on just the callback issue for now).